# Basic arithmetic on two byte arrays in Java without BigInteger

Tags: java, arrays

I have two byte arrays that represent unsigned 256-bit values and I want to perform simple arithmetic operations on them like ADD, SUB, DIV, MUL and EXP - Is there a way to perform these directly on the byte arrays? Currently I convert these byte array values to a BigInteger and then perform the calculations, but I have an idea this is costing me in performance. How would you do this to get the fastest results?

For example, this is my current add-function:

```
// Both byte arrays are length 32 and represent unsigned 256-bit values
public void add(byte[] data1, byte[] data2) {

    BigInteger value1 = new BigInteger(1, data1);
    BigInteger value2 = new BigInteger(1, data2);
    BigInteger result = value1.add(value2);

    byte[] bytes = result.toByteArray();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);

    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, buffer.array(), 32 - bytes.length, bytes.length);
    this.buffer = buffer.array();
}
```

Comment: For some reason this looks *really* familiar...

Comment: Why do you think it's costly?

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization, if you really needed the small amount of extra speed you will gain from this surely you would use a language without the overhead of Java or perhaps store your numbers as `BigInteger`s in the first place.
Yes there is a tiny overhead(How often are these operations going to be called?) in converting your byte arrays to the signum/magnitude format that they are stored within `BigInteger`, however implementing the binary arithmetic by hand would take more time and open you upto alot of possibilities for bugs in your math.

Comment: To get the fastest results, I'd convert the byte array values to a `BigInteger` and let it perform the calculations, on the theory that the people who wrote that class have already spent years making it more optimal and probably know what they're doing better than I do.

Comment: If your storing/transferring these `BigInteger`s and that is the reason your keeping them as byte arrays, perhaps Serialization would help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think that there is much benefit from working on `byte[]` directly rather than using `BigInteger` but for satisfying your curiosity here is an example of how to add two byte arrays of size `32`:

```
public static byte[] add(byte[] data1, byte[] data2) {
  if(data1.length!=32 || data2.length!=32)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  byte[] result=new byte[32];
  for(int i=31, overflow=0; i>=0; i--) {
    int v = (data1[i]&0xff)+(data2[i]&0xff)+overflow;
    result[i]=(byte)v;
    overflow=v>>>8;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note that it is possible to use one of the input arrays as target for the result. However, don’t be surprised if such a reusing has even a negative impact on performance. On today’s systems there are no simple answers to “how to speedup” anymore…

Comment: So basically just adding each byte individually. Such a simpel answer and something similar could be done for the operations. I did a performance test and came up with 4876ms vs 342ms (your solution) with 10000000 iterations. This seems significatly faster, contrary to what people say about BigInteger already being optimized. I'll have to double check the results, but this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Did you write this yourself or is there an open source implementation of these types of operations somewhere?

Comment: Well `BigInteger` has a lot more to do than this simple method, e.g. it will not discard overflow but rather allocate a larger byte array instead. So it has to handle differently sized arrays as well. So this simplified method has the potential of being faster, even if `BigInteger` is optimized, but results of a microbenchmark can differ heavily from the results of a real life application where this operation makes only a fractional part of. And it’s implementation and platform dependent. I wrote this ad hoc by myself but that doesn’t mean that there are no libraries for such task.

Comment: I am interested in more of these functions for 32-bytes values like multiply and divide. Overflows are allowed. Where would I even start looking?

Comment: Consider the byte array of size *n* to be a number with *n* digits in Base256 system. Then try to remember elementary arithmetic, i.e. how you perform these operation with large numbers [by hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#Subtraction_by_hand). I linked to Subtraction, because it has more details than the Addition article. If you compare that to the method above, you should notice the similarity. Likewise [Long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) leads to a solution, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For treating as a big unsigned number, a byte[] isn't an ideal solution, consider for example that for adding two of these numbers, you will have to loop over the two arrays, adding each byte (and the carry from the previous byte), then storing back the resulting byte somewhere.

BigInteger internally represents the value in a manner suitable for the operations it provides, so its operations will very likely be at least as good as you can do with byte[]. A slight drawback in terms of performance *might* be that BigInteger is immutable.

Performance wise, a simple, mutable holder object consisting of 4 long members would probably do best:

```
My256BitNumber {
    long l0;
    long l1;
    long l2;
    long l3;

    public void add(My256BitNumber arg) {
        //...
    }
}
```

That would allow you to bypass overhead of object creation (due to being mutable), as well as any potential array access overhead (like array index bounds checks).

But considering that none of the operations are *trivial* to implement, just make use of BigInteger. It combines reasonable performance, with reasonable simplicity of use, and most importantly - is a tested, working solution.

If rolling your own implementation is worth it, depends on your use case. Considering you're asking *if* one could get better performance than BigInteger, the answer is, yes you can - BUT at severe expense in code complexity.